# django - class view 404 if no result

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following class-based view -

```
class DeployFilterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DefinitionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        jobname = self.request.GET.get('jobname')
        if jobname.count("\\") == 1:
            jobname = jobname.replace("\\", "")
            queryset = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('Admiral').filter(jobmst_name=jobname).exclude(jobmst_prntname__isnull=True, jobmst_dirty='X')
        else:
            parent, job = jobname.rsplit('\\', 1)
            queryset = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('Admiral').filter(jobmst_prntname=parent, jobmst_name=job).exclude(jobmst_dirty='X')          

        return queryset
```

I want to have it return a 404 response if either queryset returns no information how do I go about chaining that in?

I'm using Django Rest Framework.  Right now if I call a URL and there's no data it passes a 200 OK which I don't want.  Below is what I'm trying -

```
class DeployFilterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DefinitionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        jobname = self.request.GET.get('jobname')
        if jobname.count("\\") == 1:
            jobname = jobname.replace("\\", "")
            queryset = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('Admiral').filter(jobmst_name=jobname).exclude(jobmst_prntname__isnull=True, jobmst_dirty='X')
        else:
            parent, job = jobname.rsplit('\\', 1)
            queryset = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('Admiral').filter(jobmst_prntname=parent, jobmst_name=job).exclude(jobmst_dirty='X')
        try:
            if queryset == True:
                return queryset
            else:
                raise exceptions.DoesNotExist
```

But it fails on saying my indenting is wrong but I don't see how it is.

Comment: Have you tried raising a 404 exception?

Comment: Yes trying exceptions but I'm not getting why it doesn't like my syntax.  updating to include.

Comment: You're missing a matching except clause, for one. 
Is there a particular reason you're using a try block? Could you just do `if queryset: 
return queryset
else:
raise Http404`

[Also, see django's documentation on returning a 404.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception)

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `if queryset == True:`, `if queryset:` will work the same.

Comment: Thnks that's helping!  I'm doing what you suggested I just need to get the else for the exception to point to a 404 error.

Comment: thnx got it.              if queryset:
                return queryset
            else:
                raise Http404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely throwing an issue because you have no except block. You don't need to keep the try block; since you're just doing an if/else statement.

Also, your `if queryset == True:` is unnecessary, you can just do `if queryset:`.

Try something like:

```
from django.http import Http404

# The rest of your code here...

if queryset:
    return queryset
else:
    raise Http404
```

For more information you can check out [django's documentation on returning 404 errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception).